# Image of the domain $|z|<1$, $0<\text{Arg}\,z<\pi/4$ under the mappimg $w=(2z+1)/(z+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the image of the domain $D$ under the mapping $w=\frac{2z+1}{z+i}$, where

$$D=\left\{z;|z|<1,0<\operatorname{Arg}z<\frac\pi4\right\}$$

I've tried two ways but in both I arrived to something very complex.

**First way:** Since $z=\frac{-iw+1}{w-2}$, we have $\left|\frac{-iw+1}{w-2}\right|<1$ and after some manipulation we arrive to $4u+2v<3$. Also we should have

$$0<\arctan(\frac{-u^2-v^2+2u-v}{u-2v-2})<\frac\pi4$$

Now if $u-2v-2>0$ we have $$0<\frac{-u^2-v^2+2u-v}{u-2v-2}<1$$ and if $u-2v-2<0$ we should have $-u^2-v^2+2u-v<0$

**Second way:** Let $w_1=z+i$. Then

$w_1=\left\{z;|z-i|<1,0<\text{Arg}(z-i)<\frac\pi4\right\}$. If $w_2=\frac1{w_1}$, then since $|z-i|<1$ we arrive to $2v+1<0$ and since $0<\text{Arg}(z-i)<\frac\pi4$ we arrive to $0<\frac{-v-u^2-v^2}u<1$ so again we should consider two cases $u>0$ and $u<0$.

Could anyone help me to find the right image?

Comment: Hint: Such mappings map lines and circles to lines and circles (but not necessarily lines to lines and circles to circles). Border of $D$ consists of two line segments and one circle arc ...

Comment: Using the fact that $$z=\frac{1-iw}{w-2}$$ the "first way" indeed allows to see that the condition $|z|<1$ is equivalent to $w=u+iv$ with $u$ and $v$ real and $$4u+2v<3$$ But the argument ccndition $$0<\mathrm{Arg}\zeta<\pi/4$$ reads $$0<\Im\zeta<\Re\zeta$$ hence, using the positive multiple of $z$ equal to $$\zeta=(1-iw)(\bar w-2)$$  one gets $$0<2u-u^2-v^2-v<u-2-2v$$ from where you can conclude, right?

Comment: @Antoine Two and one, or one and two?

Comment: @Did What do you mean by "using the positive multiple of $z$ equal to $\zeta=(1-iw)(\bar{w}-2)$"?

Comment: That $\zeta$ is a positive multiple of $z$ (hence their arguments are the same).